# making action buttons of the ActionBar white

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-button

I want to make the color of **action buttons** of the ActionBar `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`, **white**. I don't want to use a custom resource.
I know when i use **DarkTheme**, the buttons automatically turns to white but i am using a **transparent ActionBar** and i don't want to increase overhead by adding new resources to my application.

I was able to do this easily for the arrow button in DrawerLayout by using

`<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
 </style>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Toolbar defining the theme and the style:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        style="@style/HeaderBar"
        app:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay"/>
```

And you can have the full control of your ui elements with these styles:

```
 <style name="ActionBarThemeOverlay" parent="">
     <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fff</item>
     <item name="colorControlNormal">#fff</item>
     <item name="colorControlHighlight">#3fff</item>
 </style>


<style name="HeaderBar">
    <!-- Define the toolbar background -->
    <item name="android:background">xxxx</item>
</style>
```

Comment: my .xml displays this message on inspection

`Namespace 'app' is not bound`

Comment: I made it work by using `<item name="colorControlNormal">#fff</item>` directly as attribute but i can't  figure out how to fix that Namespace inspection error. It would do great help if you may tell me how to fix that

Comment: You have to define your custom namespace in your root element in your layout with xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"